# Dtype issue using transformer function from sklearn

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I've been receiving the following error after running the following line:

```
transformer = preprocessing.FunctionTransformer(func=np.log1p, inverse_func=np.expm1)
scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
X1_t = transformer.fit_transform(X_t)
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [103], line 3
      1 transformer = preprocessing.FunctionTransformer(func=np.log1p, inverse_func=np.expm1)
      2 scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
----> 3 X1_t = transformer.fit_transform(X_t)
      4 X2_t = scaler.fit_transform(X1_t)
      5 print(X2_t.shape)

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:867, in TransformerMixin.fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    863 # non-optimized default implementation; override when a better
    864 # method is possible for a given clustering algorithm
    865 if y is None:
    866     # fit method of arity 1 (unsupervised transformation)
--> 867     return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)
    868 else:
    869     # fit method of arity 2 (supervised transformation)
    870     return self.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_function_transformer.py:195, in FunctionTransformer.fit(self, X, y)
    193 X = self._check_input(X, reset=True)
    194 if self.check_inverse and not (self.func is None or self.inverse_func is None):
--> 195     self._check_inverse_transform(X)
    196 return self

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_function_transformer.py:160, in FunctionTransformer._check_inverse_transform(self, X)
    157 idx_selected = slice(None, None, max(1, X.shape[0] // 100))
    158 X_round_trip = self.inverse_transform(self.transform(X[idx_selected]))
--> 160 if not np.issubdtype(X.dtype, np.number):
    161     raise ValueError(
    162         "'check_inverse' is only supported when all the elements in `X` is"
    163         " numerical."
    164     )
    166 if not _allclose_dense_sparse(X[idx_selected], X_round_trip):

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:5575, in NDFrame.__getattr__(self, name)
   5568 if (
   5569     name not in self._internal_names_set
   5570     and name not in self._metadata
   5571     and name not in self._accessors
   5572     and self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name)
   5573 ):
   5574     return self[name]
-> 5575 return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

I was able to run this code before, but had to reinstall Jupyter notebook and when reinstalling and downloading all libraries, started getting this issue. My hypothesis is that it is related to combinations of versions of Jupyter + libraries (pandas, sklearn), but don't remember the versions I previously had.

Any idea?

Comment: Where exactly? Please update your question to 1) include the full error trace (as text, not screenshot) and 2) remove any code than may come *after* the error (hence never executed, hence irrelevant to the issue, hence just clutter here) - see how to create a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

Checking the Function Transformer [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer.html) shows this:

```
check_inverse: bool, default=True
Whether to check that or func followed by inverse_func leads to the original inputs. It can be used for a sanity check, raising a warning when the condition is not fulfilled.

New in version 0.20.
```

I'm guessing your version got bumped up to `>0.20` and so this is being set. I started encountering the same issue after defining the inverse transform, and setting `check_inverse = False` fixed it.